# Problema con login PHP - array(1) { ["iniciarSesion"]=> string(2) "ok" } (patrón MVC)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mvc, adminlte

estoy haciendo un proyecto basándome en Admin LTE 3.1.0, ocupo el patrón Modelo-Vista-Controlador (MVC).

El problema que tengo, es que cuando intento hacer el login con un usuario registrado, este si ocurre pero me devuelve a la página "login". Pero, en la barra del navegador aparece "inicio".

Les dejo un video, con el problema, para graficarlo mejor: https://youtu.be/rIcEDUjnkGQ

**Listas de archivos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDITO --> al agregar var_dump($_SESSION); en el archivo "plantilla.php" (más abajo añado el código), sale lo siguiente:

```
array(1) { ["iniciarSesion"]=> string(2) "ok" }
```

**El código del usuario controlador:**

```
<?php

class ControladorUsuarios{

    static public function  ctrIngresar(){

        if(isset($_POST ['ingRut'])){

                $tabla = "usuarios";
                $item = "rut";
                $valor = $_POST['ingRut'];
                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla,$item,$valor);
                
                if($respuesta['rut']==$_POST['ingRut']&&$respuesta['password']==$_POST['ingPassword']){

                $_SESSION['iniciarSesion']="ok";
                
                echo '<script> window.location = "inicio" </script>';

            } else {
                
                echo ("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'> <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button> Error! Rut o Contraseña incorrecta</div>");
            }

           

            }
        }

    }
```

Código Modelo Usuario:

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios{

    static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla,$item,$valor){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item,$valor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt ->execute();
        return $stmt ->fetch();
        $stmt ->close();
        $stmt = null;

    }

}
```

**Código login**

```
    <div class="login-box">
<div class="card card-outline card-primary">
    <div class="card-header text-center">
      <p class="h2">Centro Médico <br /> <b> Escuela de Medicina</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

    
<form method="post" role="form">
    
         <div class="input-group mb-3">
       
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ingRut" id="ingRut" maxlength="9" placeholder="RUT" >
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="ingPassword" id="ingPassword" placeholder="Contraseña" />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="social-auth-links text-center mt-2 mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" align='center'>Ingresar</button>
          </div>        </div>

        <?php
            $login = new ControladorUsuarios();
            $login -> ctrIngresar();
        ?>

      </form>

      
    <!-- /.card-body -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.card -->
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->
```

**Código Index**

```
<?php

require_once    "controladores/plantilla.controlador.php";
require_once    "controladores/usuarios.controlador.php";
require_once    "modelos/usuarios.modelo.php";
$plantilla = new ControladorPlantilla ();
$plantilla -> ctrPlantilla ();

?>
```

**Código Plantilla**

```
    <?php session_start() ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="vistas/img/logo.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Centro Médico</title>

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JQVMap -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- summernote -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
     $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button)
    </script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- ChartJS -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js"></script>
<!-- JQVMap -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vistas/plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vistas/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Summernote -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
<!-- overlayScrollbars -->
    <script src="vistas/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="vistas/dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
<!-- Full calendar -->
    <link href='vistas/fullcalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='vistas/fullcalendar/main.js'></script>
    <script src='vistas/fullcalendar/locales/es.js'></script>
    <script src='vistas/fullcalendar/json/events.json'></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
      dateClick: function(info) {
        
        $('#cita').modal();
        console.log(info);
        calendar.addEvent({title: "Event X", date:info.dateStr});
        },
        eventClick:function(info){
            console.log(info);
            console.log(info.event.title);
            console.log(info.event.start);

            console.log(info.event.end);
            console.log(info.event.textColor);
            console.log(info.event.backgroundColor);

            console.log(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);


        },
        events:[
         {
        title: "Mi evento 1",
        start: "2021-03-29 12:30:00",
        descripcion:"Descripcion evento1"
         },{
        title: "Mi evento 2",
        start: "2021-03-30 12:30:00",
        end: "2021-03-31 12:30:00",
        color: "#FFCCAA",
        textColor: "#000000",
        descripcion:"Descripcion evento2"
          }
             ],
      
      timeZone: 'local',
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      locale: 'es',
      buttonIcons: true, // show the prev/next text
      weekNumbers: false,
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      allDaySlot: false,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      weekends: false,
      slotLabelFormat:{
             hour: '2-digit',
             minute: '2-digit',
             hour12: false
             },
      eventTimeFormat: {
               hour: '2-digit',
               minute: '2-digit',
               hour12: false
              }

    });
        calendar.setOption('slotMinTime','08:00:00')
        calendar.setOption('slotMaxTime','17:00:00')
        calendar.render();
      });

    </script>


<!-- FIN SCRIPTS -->
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed login-page">

        <?php

      if(isset($_SESSION['iniciarSesion'])&&$_SESSION['iniciarSesión']=="ok"){

        echo '<div class="wrapper">';

          include "vistas/modulos/header.php";
          include "vistas/modulos/menu.php";

      if(isset($_GET['ruta'])){
          if($_GET['ruta']=="inicio"||
          $_GET['ruta']=="agendarcita"||
          $_GET['ruta']=="subirarchivo"||
          $_GET['ruta']=="salir"){

          include "vistas/modulos/".$_GET['ruta'].".php";
          
        }else{
             include "vistas/modulos/404.php";
            }
          }

      include "vistas/modulos/footer.php";

    } 

    else{

      include "vistas/modulos/login.php";
    }




    ?>

    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div class="preloader flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img class="animation__shake" src="vistas/img/logo.png" height="200" width="200">
    </div>


     
     <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
    </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
    </div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->


    </body>
    </html>
```

Estaría muy agradecido si le pudieran echar un ojo a mi código y ayudarme con este error que me tiene parado :(

Comment: ¿Dónde ejecutas `session_start();`? En inicio agrega esta línea: `var_dump($_SESSION);` y edita la pregunta para poner ahí lo que te aparece.

Comment: Hola, edite los códigos en la publicación, ahí incluí donde está el `session_start()`. Cuando le di `var_dump($_SESSION);`me sale lo siguiente: `array(1) { ["iniciarSesion"]=> string(2) "ok" }`